# Is it possible to properly integrate and run Alpine.JS on top of React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, alpine.js

I like being able to write my JavaScript functionality inside of my markup. Can I do this in JSX - inside one of my react page components like this?

About.tsx

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const About = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load Alpine.js dynamically
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3/dist/alpine.js';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Clean up function to remove the script when component unmounts
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <div>About Page</div>
    <h1 x-data="{ message: 'I ❤️ Alpine' }" x-text="message"></h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

**NOTE - Alpine.js looks for x-init and x-data functions on the global scope. I need to define my functions as window properties.**

I've asked GPT for help, and it lead me to believe that this integration is pointless since my JavaScript logic isn't conveniently defined in the markup itself. Here is the code it gave me:

ChatGPT's response for changing About.tsx

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const About = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load Alpine.js dynamically
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3/dist/alpine.js';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Clean up function to remove the script when component unmounts
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  // Attach x-data to window object
  useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure Alpine is loaded
    if (window.Alpine) {
      window.Alpine.data('message', () => ({ message: 'I ❤️ Alpine' }));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <div>About Page</div>
    <h1 x-data="window.message" x-text="message"></h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

The JavaScript gets loaded in the main html, however it doesn't work. I think it's because AlpineJS needs access to the global scope and React wraps it's code within modules?

Comment: Hi Solus and welcome to SO. Could you explain to us what the point is to using two tools that have the same purpose?

Comment: Simple answer: Don't do it. As @EmielZuurbier mentioned, both tools have the same purpose and they _will_ mess up with each other and you'll run into all sorts of troubles. For example: When rendering, React creates an in-memory tree structure that resembles the DOM that the browser sees. However, when Alpine runs, it _modifies_ the browser's DOM but it will _not_ synchronize the in-memory tree structure of React. What do you think will happen on _next render_?

Comment: And besides: React allows writing JS inside the markup via JSX, it's just that it _works_ different. Therefor I just started wondering what you want to achieve by using Alpine (besides the already mentioned troubles)?

Comment: Yes, guys I realized that I was just being a bit oblivious. It is indeed the same thing, however thanks for the input. I appreciate the insights. Alpine is cool, but that's another ball game. React and Next does it natively.